# ETIMEOUT during file upload. SAILS JS

Tags: javascript, file-upload, sails.js

I have a form with file upload field. Its working fine if I upload file. But when I submit the form with out file it redirects to the expected page and gives ETIMEOUT error too.

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: ETIMEOUT: An Upstream (`NOOP_avatar`) timed out waiting
iles were sent after waiting 500ms.
    at null.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\fileuploadtest\node_m
ndalone\Upstream\Upstream.js:58:15)
```

My code looks something like this:

```
upload_image: function (req, res) {
    var uploadPath = '../../assets/images/uploads/';
    console.log(req.file('avatar')._files);
    if(req.file('avatar')._files.length > 0){
      req.file('avatar').upload({
          saveAs: function(file, cb) {
            cb(null, file.filename);
          },
          dirname: uploadPath
        }, function whenDone(err, uploadedFiles) {
          if (err){
            return res.serverError(err);
          } else{
            return res.view('showimage', {file:uploadedFiles});
          }
        });
    }else{
      console.log('no data');
       return res.view('showimage');
    }
  },
```

It redirect to showimage but gives error too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using req.file('avatar') will try to check for files uploaded which has not yet been uploaded so using if condition will give you an error. Try using the if condition after using .upload() function.

```
req.file('avatar').upload({
  saveAs: function(file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.filename);
  },
  dirname: uploadPath
}, function whenDone(err, uploadedFiles) {
  if (err){
    return res.serverError(err);
  } 
  if(uploadedFiles.length!=0){
    return res.view('showimage', {file:uploadedFiles});
  }else{
   return res.view('showimage', {file:"No files uploaded."});
   }
});
```